# Can't install scala in emacs - An error occurred while loading `/home/nazar_art/.emacs'

Tags: scala, emacs, installation

I tried to install Scala accord this [Set up for learning Scala with Emacs](http://tuxdna.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/set-up-for-learning-scala-with-emacs/).

My current OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

I did exactly step by step.

After installation I run Emacs and see next error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/nazar_art/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, scala-mode-auto

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I guessed that it is problem with permission. I change it for `scala-mode` but without success.

Here is content of `~/.emacs.d`:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~/.emacs.d$ ls -lg
total 12
drwx------ 2 nazar_art 4096 Oct 10 10:58 auto-save-list
drwxrwxr-x 4 nazar_art 4096 Oct  5 00:12 elpa
drwxrwxrwx 4 nazar_art 4096 Oct 10 10:41 scala-mode
```

I'm newly at emacs and not sure that can find cause of error follow my intuition.
Any suggestion?

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/scala-mode")(require 'scala-mode-auto)` => The file
`~/.emacs.d/scala-mode/scala-mode-auto.el` must be present.

Comment: @abo-abo Where can I get this file? Because it doesn't present there. How this one was ommited....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Install Scala

   ```
   sudo apt-get install scala
   ```
2. Get `scala-mode`

   ```
   cd ~/git
   git clone git://github.com/tuxdna/scala-mode.git
   ```
3. Set up the `load-path`

   ```
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/git/scala-mode")
   ```
4. Require `scala-mode-auto`

   ```
   (require 'scala-mode-auto)
   ```
5. Created my first Scala source `~/first.scala`. The mode was loaded.

   ```
   object First {
     def main(args: Array[String]) {
       println("Test")
     }
   }
   ```
6. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `scala-run-scala`
7. Loaded the source with <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd>.
8. Entered `First.main(null)` in the interpreter. The program ran.

Comment: At #7 I have some trouble - it prints - `C-c Tab is indifined`. As I see it should be `C-c C-l` (the last is little L ??). Because it prints `<console>:8: error: not found: value First
              First.main(null)`. After #6 - I have correct scala repl.

Comment: Yes, it's a small L. And you need to be in the scala buffer when you `C-c C-l`.

Comment: It prints `no history`. How can I load source at any another way?

Comment: That's because you call it from `*inferior-scala*` buffer. You need to call it from `first.scala`.